# Something like a reversed random number generator

Tags: algorithm, montecarlo, prng, lossy-compression

I really don't know what the name of this problem is, but it's something like lossy compression, and I have a bad English, but I will try to describe it as much as I can.

Suppose I have list of unsorted unique numbers from unknown source, the length is usually between 255 to 512 with a range from 0 to 512.
I wonder if there is some kind of an algorithm that reads the data and return something like a seed number that I can use to generate a list somehow close to the original but with some degree of error.

For example

- original list

  ```
  {5, 13, 25, 33, 3, 10}
  ```
- regenerated list

  ```
  {4, 10, 30, 30, 5, 5} or {8, 20, 20, 35, 5, 9} //and so on
  ```

Does this problem have a name, and is there an algorithm that can do what I just described?
Is it the same as **Monte Carlo method** because from what I understand it isn't.

Is it possible to use some of the techniques used in lossy compression to get this kind of approximation ?

What I tried to do to solve this problem is to use a simple 16 bit RNG and brute-force all the possible values comparing them to the original list and pick the one with the minimum difference, but I think this way is rather dumb and inefficient.

Comment: Still need more description to solve your problem.

Comment: I think you want to add 'noise' to the original list right?

Comment: it is something like lossy compression

Comment: You could approximate this sequence with a polynomial. In a simple case, that would be a linear function that just passes all points with minimal distance. Using higher order polynomials you could achieve an even better approximation. Trying to condense the whole range of numbers into a single 16-bit number without severe loss (up to complete unrecognizability) is probably not possible.

Comment: i used 16 bit number because my approach is based on brute force, imagine 255 bit number this would be insane, but it's OK to use a 255 bit number or bigger (in a form of bit array of course) as long as it's fast.

Comment: Is there any relation between the numbers in the sequence that you could exploit? If it's e.g. a waveform, you could use a Fourier transformation or something like that.

Comment: unfortunately there isn't

Comment: You never mention what is your `random` there are many ways in which a random number can be generated. Your problem definitely sounds like polynomial interpolation, but it is hard to understand what exactly is that you want.

Comment: What kind of errer metric are you working with?  Do you want small average error, few wrong values, or few bit errors?

Comment: Do you need the candidate generator to have other qualities for extrapolation or interpolation?  Sort of like fractal compression or something.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed lossy compression.

You don't tell us the range of the values in the list. From the samples you give we can extrapolate that they count at least 6 bits each (0 to 63). In total, you have from 0 to 3072 bits to compress.

If these sequences have no special property and appear to be random, I doubt there is any way to achieve significant compression. Think that the probability of an arbitrary sequence to be matched from a 32 bits seed is 2^32.2^(-3072)=7.10^(-916), i.e. less than infinitesimal. If you allow 10% error on every value, the probability of a match is 2^32.0.1^512=4.10^(-503).

A trivial way to compress with 12.5% accuracy is to get rid of the three LSB of each value, leading to 50% savings (1536 bits), but I doubt this is what you are looking for.

Would be useful to measure the entropy of the sequences [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) and/or possible correlations between the values. This can be done by plotting all (V, Vi+1) pairs, or (Vi, Vi+1, Vi+2) triples and looking for patterns.